# How to verify the data which was created in the same testcase in Tosca?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, rpa, tosca

I am working on Tosca tool, I created a test-step in which I gave some input like Title and uploaded a file in one portal...Later in that same test-case I have to give another test step in which I able to verify title and able to download the file in another portal.

How am I able to give the test-step for the second portal??

Thank you...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filename before hand, you could use a Test Configuration Parameter or a Business Parameter to pass it to your TC.

Otherwise, you could use a Buffer to temporarily save your filename, and recall it later on.